# How to listen for Database-changes using an RestAPI from Google/Microsoft/Notion?

Tags: node.js, rest, notion-api

I am trying to integrate *Google Calendar* and *Microsoft Todo* into my Notion Workspace using *NodeJS*. It is quite easy to make Requests in order to create, read, update and delete data but I was wondering how I could listen for changes in the database. For instance if someone creates an event in Google Calendar, how can I directly respond to this change in Google's database by creating a new event in the Notion Database? I thought of making as many requests per minute as possible in order to notice changes as early as possible, but I do not think that is quite resource friendly.

Eventually I was also wondering if it is even possible to make a RestAPI-Server that sends out some kind of *Notifications*.

I hope my question is understandable.
Thank you and stay save!

Answer (score 1):

They keyword you're looking for is "webhook", I don't know if Google Calendar and Microsoft Todo support webhook or not but Notion currently doesn't, learn more at https://www.reddit.com/r/Notion/comments/nd76ec/notion_api_webhooks/